# How do I use percentages to create an adjustable web page?

Tags: html, css, percentage, adjustable

I am creating a game of jeopardy, I need to make my web page adjustable with the window size using percentages. How do I do that?
I have all the padding and margins in ems,but I don't know how to change them to percentages.

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow. Please consider doing some research or reading some tutorials on responsive web design. If you *then* have a **specific** question about a programming problem you've run into (that isn't already asked/answered of course) you can ask it here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

- Can use bootstrap.
- make it auto.

or if you can put your sample code in fiddle then i can see.

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to **set the width of the parent div to a percentage value**.
This way even though the your padding and margins are in em's (as you mentioned above) the width of the div will still be set to a percentage value and hence fluid.